# Azure API App: Which versions of Python are supported?

Tags: python, azure, azure-api-apps

I can't seem to find a clear answer regarding which versions of Python are supported by Azure API Apps.  Azure API Apps as we know run within an App Service.  I need to know which versions of the Python interpreter are installed on Azure App Services by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information live by connecting to a Kudu console and use "python --version" and "python3 --version". At least this is accurate even if it changes over the time.

I believe it's python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4.1, but it's a guess and probably not that right now.

You should also read this article on how on update Python on AppService (even if it's not directly your question). Because this helps you to control the version:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/